# Regular expression to exclude folders in url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm rewriting url with .htaccess. 
I need to write a regular expression to exclude some folders in a rewriting rule. I red a few similar questions but it still doesn't work.
I want to remove .php from www.mywebsite.it/page.php, www.mywebsite.it/eng/page.php and www.mywebsite.it/ita/page.php

Those are my rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?!ita|eng)([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ /$1 [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ita/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ ita/$1 [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule eng/([^x]+).php$ eng/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

the second and the third are working, but not the first one.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried a lot of thinks but when the rule works it goes into conflict with the others.

UPDATE: 
here's the rules I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).it$ $1/index.php?lang=it [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)eng/$ $1/index.php?lang=en [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^ita/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+)$ $1.php?lang=it [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eng/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+)$ $1.php?lang=en [NC,L]
```

That part works and I did it for seo optimization.
Now I have to redirect the old urls of the website (I changed the structure of my website without changing domain).

Before the structure was: www.mywebsite.it/page.html (for the italian language) www.mywebsite.it/eng/page.html (for the english)

and the new structure is: www.mywebsite.it/ita/newpage.php (italian) and www.mywebsite.it/eng/newpage.php (english)

So I tried:

```
#html to php
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1.php [R=302]

Redirect 302 /page.php http://www.mywebsite.it/ita/newpage.php   
Redirect 302 /eng/page.php http://www.mywebsite.it/eng/newpage.php

#remove php
RewriteRule ita/([A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+).php$ ita/$1 [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule eng/([^x]+).php$ eng/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

But when I visit eng/page.html I'm redirected to eng/ita/newpage

Then I thought that I could change the new structure and eliminate the folder ita/ for the italian language (to keep things more similar as possibile to the old structure and so I just have to redirect "page" into "newpage" without messing with the folders...), but when I try to set a rule without ita/ or eng/ I end up in conflicts or loop.
That's why I'm looking for a regular expression to say (something but not ita or eng).

Comment: Take a look at `RewriteCond`. That will make your code set much easier to read.

Comment: Besides it looks like all you lack is a `/` in the first rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule, which combine all cases

```
RewriteRule ^(ita/|eng/|)([^/]+)\.php$ /$1$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Your first rule was not working because never matched. Indeed, in htaccess context, there is no leading slash to match. There was also a conflict/matching issue because of your negative lookahead `?!` and the filename part.

## Update

Following your update, here is the corresponding code

```
# (1) *.html -> *.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [R=302,L,NC]

# (2) /page.php to /ita/newpage.php and /eng/page.php to /eng/newpage.php
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /ita/newpage.php [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^eng/page\.php$ /eng/newpage.php [R=302,L,NC]

# (3) /ita/page.php or /ita/page (same for eng) and /page.php to /page
RewriteRule ^(ita/|eng/|)([^/]+)\.php$ /$1$2 [R=302,L,NC]

# (4) rewrite to /file.php?lang=xx
RewriteRule ^ita/(.+)$ /$1.php?lang=it [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eng/(.+)$ /$1.php?lang=en [L,NC]
```

Note: (3) will be useless (except for `/ita/`) because of (2) which will match instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I tried as you suggested, but yet another conflict because I have another set of url after to rewrite into the actual url with the query... and I prefer to keep the three rules separated because the folder ita/ corresponds to the query ?lang=it and eng/ is ?lang=en. I need something to say (everything but ita or eng) in the first rule so that the three cases are treated different. Hope I explained myself! I'm not an expert at all

Comment: Please update your question with your other rules, I'll take care of it

Comment: OK I did it! My problem is actually a little different from the question I asked! I thought it could be a good way to find a solution.

Comment: Kinda weird. I tried to update my answer taking your explanation into consideration but I'm not sure I got everything of this spaghetti url scheme

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working!! Number 3 is causing problems because it removes the .php in the actual url with the query string. But if I keep ita/ and eng/ separated it's fine (I don't need to rewrite page.php into page if number 2 works). So I have number 3: ^ita/(.+).php$ ita/$1 [R=302,NC] and ^eng/(.+).php$ ita/$1 [R=302,NC]. I took off the L flag in rules numer 1,2 and 3 because it causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set, I'm I right? Thanks again!!!